# Не прогружается изображение в созданном шаблоне WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, html5

Добрый вечер уважаемые формучане, осваиваю создание сайтов, в колледже дано одно задание.. Решил создать шаблон пустой php страницы с подключенным хедером и футером. Подключил через панель, выбрав шаблон. Отображает элементы, но не отображает картинки:( Возможно я чего-то не понимаю в создании страниц WP, страницу создал, в блок меню она есть. На других страницах (например front-page.php) эти же картинки картинки есть. (файл шаблона лежит в той же директории, что и другие файлы страниц, путь к фотографии аналогичен)
Пожалуйста, помогите, перепробовал всё, подключал через php, указывал путь через css. Без результатов, в интернете нужной информации по подобной проблеме нету..
Вот код шаблона страницы:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: MYTEMPS
 */
get_header();
?>
<h1>TEST</h1>
 <img src="wp-content/assets/img/London2.jpg">
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

[image: Проблемная страница:]

Comment: Вы указали относительный путь к картинке, а не абсолютный. Относительный путь  высчитывается относительно текущего местоположения.

Comment: попробуйте указать просто ` <img src="/wp-content/assets/img/London2.jpg">` со слешем в начале

Comment: /wp-content ... Слэш впереди

Comment: Да, работает! Большое вам спасибо! Про слэш как-то и не подумал, т.к  на других страницах картинки отображаются и без него. Прошу прощения за мою невнимательность.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо за ответы :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что за странный путь? Не нужно так делать) если картинка должна быть статичной и не устанавливается через пост, то нужно добавить ее в тему например по такой структуре `wp-content/themes/you_theme/assets/img/London2.jpg` и потом уже отобразить ее например так

`<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/London2.jpg">`

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)